# Android : order of filtering in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

My doubt is regarding the order in which the elements of the manifest files are taken for filtering in Google Play, I mean which element would have the higher priority in the filtering process.

As far as my understanding goes the elements < compatible-screens > and < supports-screens > does the functionality of filtering the devices that can download your application right.

But how would the filtering happen if I have both these elements in my manifest but with conflicting values?

For Eg, my Compatible-Screen element says small screen elements are supported but I also have the Support-Screen element in my manifest that sets android:smallScreens="false".

Is there any sites where i could read more in the similar lines?
Everything i searched for filtering mentions what each attributes does. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood was that there is no priority set for the attributes in the manifest file,
the system would behave in different ways on seeing the attributes of the support screens and compatible-screen elements.
and as far as possible the developer should refrain from using the compatible screens elements.
Not sure though how the system would react if conflicting values are present.